# Applescript System Preferences automation

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, system, ui-automation

I'm working on automating setting system preferences, but I have a problem. This code should select Wi-Fi tab but scroll area 1 does not exist unless I click any element that belongs to scroll area manually. I tried emulating click with many external programs but even then I can't access scroll area

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences"
    delay 1

    tell scroll area 1 of window 1
        select row 3 of outline 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Is there any other way to change Dock & Menu Bar settings or just to access scroll area items?

Edit: The end goal is to hide Wi-Fi icon from menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The end goal is to hide Wi-Fi icon from menu bar.

**UI Scripting** of **System Preferences** in **macOS Big Sur** has become a nightmare, as many of the methods that used to work in previous versions of **macOS** just no longer do in **macOS Big Sur**. Many **UI elements** report **Parent does not report element as one of its children** when using **Accessibility Inspector** of **Xcode**, which then make it impossible to communicate with them. Or some *code* may work one time and then not the next. I wrote some *code* that opened to **Wi-Fi** and clicked the **Show in Menu Bar** *checkbox*. It worked a few times and now it doesn't.

The original *code* I wrote which sporadically worked I'll not post, however, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does consistently work as tested under **macOS Big Sur** 11.4, albeit it is what I consider *kludgy* **UI Scripting**, as it's visible on screen, is prone to failure due to timing issues, or if the *hierarchical* **UI element** *structures* change due to **macOS** updates/upgrades.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** 11.4 with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

This *script* requires that the **Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* is checked on the **System Preferences** >  **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** tab, and as coded, the *script* checks its status and toggles the *checkbox*, as necessary, based on its current status.

This *script* also first checks to see if the **Wi-Fi** icon is shown on the **Menu Bar** and if not, then halt execution of the script, as its purpose is to act only if it is shown on the **Menu Bar**.

---

### *Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    "com.apple.controlcenter.plist"

-- Get the value of 'NSStatusItem Visible WiFi' to determine if the
-- Wi-Fi icon is showing on the Menu Bar, and if it's not, then halt
-- execution of the script, as its purpose is to act only if it is.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set |Wi-Fi Menu Bar Icon Status| to the value of ¬
            the property list item ¬
                "NSStatusItem Visible WiFi"

if |Wi-Fi Menu Bar Icon Status| is false then return


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    ".GlobalPreferences.plist"

--  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
--  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
--  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
--  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set keyboardNavigation to the value of ¬
            the property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Check the checkbox.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

--  # Open System Preferences to the Dock & Menu Bar pane.
--  # 
--  # This UI Script needs it to be visible, hence the activate command.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set i to 0
    repeat until exists window "Dock & Menu Bar" of ¬
        application process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.1
        set i to i + 1
        if i ≥ 30 then return
    end repeat
end tell

--  # Tab to the 'Show in Menu Bar' checkbox and uncheck it.

tell application "System Events"
    key code 48 -- # tab key
    delay 0.2
    key code 125 -- # down arrow key
    delay 0.2
    key code 48 -- # tab key
    delay 0.2
    key code 49 -- # spacebar
    delay 0.1
end tell

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Uncheck the checkbox if it
    --  # was previously unchecked.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit


--  # Handler(s) #


--  # Toggles checkbox: 'Use keyboard navigation 
--  # to move focus between controls'

on toggleKeyboardNavagition()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
            pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of ¬
            application process "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end toggleKeyboardNavagition
```

---

**Notes:**

If the normal state of the **Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* is unchecked, then do not run the *script* immediately back to back as it takes a second or two for the *value* of the `property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"` in the **users** *global preferences file* to update the change. I'm mentioning this mainly for when doing testing more so than when in normal production use, as it shouldn't be an issue then.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>